# get date records between today and beginning of the current week

Tags: oracle, date, sysdate

suppose we have the table `error_log`, sth easily like:

```
+-------------+---------------+
| error_token | date_recorded |
+-------------+---------------+
| error_1     | 05.03.2017    |
+-------------+---------------+
| error_2     | 05.03.2017    |
+-------------+---------------+
| error_3     | 10.03.2017    |
+-------------+---------------+
| error_4     | 30.03.2017    |
+-------------+---------------+
```

what is the best way to get all errors that happened from **the beginning of the current week** till **today**.

and also the same if we want to get all errors between from **the beginning of the current month** till **today**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "until today" I have assume that means up to, but not including, any part of today which is *less than trunc(sysdate)*

```
select *
from error_log
where date_recorded >= trunc(sysdate,'W') -- beginning of week
and date_recorder < trunc(sysdate) -- optional

select *
from error_log
where date_recorded >= trunc(sysdate,'MONTH') -- beginning of month
and date_recorder < trunc(sysdate) -- optional
```

see [TRUNC](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/trunc_date.php)

Comment: thank you, that just worked fine. if I want to include the errors that have been recorded till this moment then I should use `date_recorder < sysdate`, right?  @Used_By_Already

Comment: correct, but in truth you probably don't need that upper boundary (how can an error be recorded into the future?) which is why I marked those predicates as optional. if an error greater than beginning of this week, logically it is prior to "now"